# Remove the httpclient to htttpurlconnection

Tags: android, post

In this example I use the httpclient for a post request, and I can't do the same with the httpurlconnection. Here I leave the method to see if you can help me.

The first thing I do is set the url for the request with the parameters that we are going to send it.

And then I use the response code that the request sends me.

```
public void sendBills(String idClient, String email, String bills, int retries, boolean original, boolean pdf, boolean excel, boolean withPhotoPDF, boolean withPhotoExcel, boolean imgs) {
        try {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL + "sendBill");

            //PARAMS
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idClient", idClient));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bills", bills));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("original", original + ""));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pdf", pdf + ""));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("excel", excel + ""));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("withPhotoPDF", withPhotoPDF+ ""));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("withPhotoExcel", withPhotoExcel+ ""));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imgs", imgs + ""));

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);

            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                if (!result.equals("1")) {
                    error = "1- Connection error: please, try again.";
                }
            } else {
                error = "Server error: please, try again later.";
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Globals g = Globals.getInstance();
            StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
            g.putLog(errors.toString());

            if (retries < 3) {
                retries++;
                sendBills(idClient, email, bills, retries, original, pdf, excel, withPhotoPDF, withPhotoExcel, img);
            } else {
                error = "There was a server error, please try again later.";
            }
        }
    }
```

I need you to do the same.

Comment: Attach the code the that you tried and post the error log if any.

Comment: Dont have any error, the problem is Httpclient is deprecated with 33 sdk